# MegaPot 1.2 All-Grain Brewing System VS Northern Brewer All Grain Cooler System

Tags: beer, all-grain, brewing, beer-styles, kettle

MegaPot 1.2 All-Grain Brewing System VS Northern Brewer All Grain Cooler System

Does any one know which one of these systems is more reliable?

I’m not looking to build my own; I just want to buy a full system.

or can you recommend another system?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with either, but taking a look on Northern Brewer's website I am guessing you are comparing:

This [cooler system](https://www.northernbrewer.com/products/northern-brewer-all-grain-system) with this [mega pot system](https://www.northernbrewer.com/collections/starter-kits-for-new-brewers/products/premium-craft-brewery-in-a-box-beer-making-starter-kit).

If it were me, given the similar prices, I would go for the one with a chunk of stainless at its heart, the Mega Pot, as it will last you a lifetime with a few replacement seals, and valve seats. Then you can add/replace/extend as you want or grow in your craft.